# WPF: How to open a ContextMenu from all areas of a Grid control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, contextmenu

I'm trying to add a ContextMenu to items in a ListBox in WPF;

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
       <Border>                         
             <Grid>
                <Grid.ContextMenu>
                    <ContextMenu>                                    
                       <MenuItem Header = "Menu item 1"/>
                       <MenuItem Header = "Menu item 2"/>
                       <MenuItem Header = "Menu item 3"/>
                    </ContextMenu>
                </Grid.ContextMenu>
                   ........
                   ........
             </Grid>
         </Border>
       </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

The problem is that the ContextMenu will only open when clicking on the actual context of the Grid, I want to be able to open the menu by clicking anywhere on the Listbox item.

Should I wrap the Grid in some other control?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13420994/how-to-display-context-menu-for-treeview-item-in-a-hierarchial-data-template-in/28310591#28310591

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It has been a several months since I've done any solid WPF development (was moved from application development to an actual game team).

From memory, you want to set the `ContextMenu` property on the `Border` and then set the `Border.Background=Transparent`. Setting the background to transparent ensures that it will be participate in the hit detection.

Alternative solution, would be ensure you `Grid` element stretches horizontally and vertically to fit the container.

...

Also pull the `ContextMenu` out as a static resource, so that is will be easier to find/edit in the future.

Hope this helps (and my memory does not fail me).

**EDIT:** I have answered a similar question on StackOverflow previously, please see my answer on [WPF: Displaying a Context Menu for a GridView's Items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/747872/wpf-displaying-a-context-menu-for-a-gridviews-items/). This answer is more complete as it sets the focus on the `ListItem`.

Answer (score 10):

As you have already realized, - thanks to Dennis, - you have to set some background. Yes, transparent background is also OK:

```
         <Grid Background="Transparent">
            <Grid.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu>                                    
                   <MenuItem Header = "Menu item 1"/>
                   <MenuItem Header = "Menu item 2"/>
                   <MenuItem Header = "Menu item 3"/>
                </ContextMenu>
            </Grid.ContextMenu>
               ........
               ........
         </Grid>
```

REFERENCE: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/domgreen/2008/12/08/wpf-hit-testing-with-event-bubbling/