# WPF MVVM bind command to treeview context menu

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, treeview

I have a treeview and i want have a menu on right click. On clicking menu item a command should get called with the item. I have tried different solution but keep getting error as below.

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.UserControl', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression
```

My treeview is as below

```
   <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Buildings}" Tag="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" Grid.RowSpan="4">
                    <TreeView.Resources>
                        <HierarchicalDataTemplate  ItemsSource="{Binding Gates}" DataType="{x:Type local:Floor}">

                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Floors}" DataType="{x:Type local:Building}">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" >
                                    <TextBlock.ContextMenu>
                                        <ContextMenu>
                                            <ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
                                                <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
                                                    <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=DataContext.EditCmd}"/>
                                                </Style>
                                            </ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
                                        </ContextMenu>
                                    </TextBlock.ContextMenu>
                                </TextBlock>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Gate}">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </TreeView.Resources>
                </TreeView>
```

Also in viewmodel

```
   private ICommand editCmd;
    public ICommand EditCmd
    {
        get
        {
            if (editCmd == null)
                editCmd = new DelegateCommand(EditObjectFunction);
            return editCmd;
        }
    }
```

I have tried different solution like [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13420994/how-to-display-context-menu-for-treeview-item-in-a-hierarchial-data-template-in) but could not solve the problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RelativeSource binding from a ToolTip or ContextMenu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3668654/relativesource-binding-from-a-tooltip-or-contextmenu)

Comment: It does not have treeview and I have tried the solution provided there. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried Path=Tag.EditCmd ?

Answer (score 0):

The `UserControl` is not a visual ancestor of the `MenuItem` since a `ContextMenu` resides in its own element tree.

But you could bind the `Tag` property of the `TextBlock` to the `UserControl` and then bind the `Command` property of the `MenuItem` to the `PlacementTarget` property of the `ContextMenu`:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Tag="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}">
        <TextBlock.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
                        <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}, Path=PlacementTarget.Tag.DataContext.EditCmd}"/>
                    </Style>
                </ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
            </ContextMenu>
        </TextBlock.ContextMenu>
    </TextBlock>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: This is the error I am getting with above solution.System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.UserControl', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:(no path); DataItem=null; target element is 'TreeView' (Name=''); target property is 'Tag' (type 'Object')

Comment: Is the TreeView really located inside a UserControl then? I doubt it. Please post your full XAML.