# Create separate context menu for listview and for listview item

Tags: wpf, listview, contextmenu

I have working context menu for listview control in my WPF app. I'd like to have context menu items enabled if user right clicks on listview item but disabled them is click occurs on panel area of listview.
Thanks
MK

Update: this is the my list view that works but I'd like to disable MenuItems "Remove" and "Calculate" when user clicks on panel area. Thanks for responding

```
          <ListView Name="lb_proplist"  DisplayMemberPath ="Name" HorizontalAlignment="Left" ToolTip="Use right click to see more options"  
                  ItemsSource="{Binding  Converter={StaticResource FilterByPropTypeConverter}}" Margin="0,0,0,0" 
                  ContextMenuOpening="ContextMenu_ContextMenuOpening" >


          <ListView.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu >
              <MenuItem Name="cmi_addNew" Header="Add New"
                  Command="{Binding AddNewItemItem}"
                  CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}}" />
              <MenuItem Name="cmi_remove" Header="Remove"
                  Command="{Binding RemoveItem}"
                  CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}, 
                  Path=PlacementTarget.SelectedItem}" />
              <MenuItem Name="cmi_calculate" Header="Calculate"
                  Command="{Binding CalculateItem}"
                  CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}, 
                  Path=PlacementTarget.SelectedItem}" />

            </ContextMenu>
          </ListView.ContextMenu>
          <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
              <GridViewColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" Width="200"/>
            </GridView>
          </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

Comment: Can you post your code which you have tried but not working?

Answer (score 4):

Well, this can be done using **ItemsTemplate** property for ListView:

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <DockPanel Tag = "{Binding DataContext, ElementName=myListView}">

            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>

            <DockPanel.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu>
                    <MenuItem Header="Local Item 1" 
                              Command="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget.Tag.CommandName, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}}"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="Local Item 2"/>
                </ContextMenu>
            </DockPanel.ContextMenu>

        </DockPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

In example, **ContextMenu** is created only for items, but not for whole control.
Also, **Tag** is added into **DockPanel** to access original DataContext.

---

Well, in case of **GridView** you need to override style for **ListViewItem**, and bind **ContextMenu** as **StaticResource**.

```
                <ListView.Resources>
                    <ContextMenu x:Key="ItemContextMenu">
                        <MenuItem Header="Add New"/>
                    </ContextMenu>
                </ListView.Resources>
                <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                        <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource ItemContextMenu}"/>
                    </Style>
                </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Please, take a look at [this article and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/747872/wpf-displaying-a-context-menu-for-a-gridviews-items).